# php regular form and input

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to get the search box from this site, I use php regular the form part, but there still has many other html code in it. So how to remove them and just get a pure search box? Thanks.

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('http://bingphp.codeplex.com');
preg_match_all('~<form.+</form>~iUs', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You wouldn't be able to use the form...

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regex problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645818/php-regex-problem)

Comment: @mario, hi, I still see the question in other web-site, I am so curious，I also want to know how to solve. So I copied the question and ask here. But here are also have one in your hyperlink. So the question looks repeat. I will close it. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) parser ?

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://bingphp.codeplex.com/');
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form');
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
  echo simplexml_import_dom($node)->asXML();
}
```

**PS**

> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE **COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS** "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Comment: Using the HTML Parser is the only solution for a question like this.

Comment: how to use DomDocument? I just use your code ,but still get many other html code back.

Comment: @cj333 - are you looking for the `form` in javascript?

Comment: I want to get the code just like `ClemDesm`'s code, only `<form>` and `<input>`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the *search box*. why not using *your* own search box ?

```
<form action="http://bingphp.codeplex.com/Wiki/Search.aspx" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="Home" />
    <input type="text" name="SearchText" value="PHP" />
    <input type="submit" value="Let's vamp the search" />
</form>
```

I'm not even sure the `hidden` input must be here (depends if they check it on their side).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and create your own form with the same fields and just change the `action` attribute to the same `action` target of the original site.

It won't always work though.